# Within a duty based framework, are apologies contingent on the harmed party's acknowledgement of or contrition for wrongdoing?

Tags: ethics, duty

During the debate on whether Obama should apologise for the US atomic bombing of Hiroshima and Nagasaki, as well as some people making [trolley problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trolley_problem) style comments about how many would have been killed had the atomic bombing not happened, others have argued that Japan has not shown sufficient acknowledgement of and/or contrition for its wrong-doings in World War II.

Within a broadly deontological (duty-based) framework, is offering an apology generally to be contingent upon a harmed party's acknowledgement of, or contrition for, its own wrongdoing?

(Disclaimers: This is assuming that an entire nation can be a harmed party or a wrong-doer, and it's also assuming that apologising won't cause Japan to commit harmful acts in the future.)

Comment: I'm genuinely interested in problems of forgiveness (see http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/forgiveness/ for a good start), but there really hard to work with and not very well handled by the literature in part because of the sort of issues your question highlights.

Comment: @virmaior when tagging the question, I couldn't find many other questions on forgiveness. I was wondering why...

Comment: @virmaior I'm not very knowledgeable about philosophy - I wouldn't be surprised if my question is closed because I don't ask in terms of a specific framework. Sorry (oh the irony!).

Comment: @virmaior duty.

Comment: Okay, I've made some emendations to the question to specify a duty-based framework. I'm not entirely sure why there aren't many questions on forgiveness, but it may be that forgiveness is largely a theological category. (it's hard to find closely equivalent notions outside the Abrahamic monotheisms)

Comment: For obvious reasons, it's gotten pretty big in the twentieth and twenty first centuries. One thinker we might look to is Levinas -- who does have some duty-based considerations of whether jews can forgive for the deaths that happened in the holocaust.